# How can i change this weather forecast widget position on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I went to accuweather.com site to this area:

[Accuweather](http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets?utm_source=adc&utm_medium=ExtraAd&utm_campaign=FreeWidget)

And got the right top widget.
Copied the code to my site:

```
<a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/il/hod-hasharon/212527/current-weather/212527" class="aw-widget-legal">
<!--
By accessing and/or using this code snippet, you agree to AccuWeather’s terms and conditions (in English) which can be found at http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets/terms and AccuWeather’s Privacy Statement (in English) which can be found at http://www.accuweather.com/en/privacy.
-->
</a><div id="awtd1399327708942" class="aw-widget-36hour"  data-locationkey="" data-unit="f" data-language="en-us" data-useip="true" data-uid="awtd1399327708942" data-editlocation="true"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script>
```

But it put the widget in the middle on this page and i want it to put it on the right side over the long black coming down just under the digital clock.

This is how it look now on my site:

[My Test Site](http://newsxpressmedia.com/)

EDIT

This is what i did in the main-wrap:

```
<div id="main-wrap">
<div id="sidebar" style="float:right;">
    <a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/il/hod-hasharon/212527/current-weather/212527" class="aw-widget-legal">
<!--
By accessing and/or using this code snippet, you agree to AccuWeather’s terms and conditions (in English) which can be found at http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets/terms and AccuWeather’s Privacy Statement (in English) which can be found at http://www.accuweather.com/en/privacy.
-->
</a><div id="awtd1399327708942" class="aw-widget-36hour"  data-locationkey="" data-unit="f" data-language="en-us" data-useip="true" data-uid="awtd1399327708942" data-editlocation="true"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script>
```

Is that right ? And i have tall-header.html short-header.html no-header.html and landing.html in what one of them to add it to in the main-wrap they all have div main-wrap.

Comment: You can't just throw the provided code in your website and to hope that everything will be alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That long, black area is part of the background of your page.

1. Create a div within `<div id="main-wrap">` that represents the area where you want the widget to be. `<div id="sidebar" style="float:right;"></div>` will do.
2. Copy the widget code into the new div

Comment: The div I'm referring to is the main wrapper of all the content on your page. You shouldn't have to modify the Accuweather div at all.

Comment: agressen edited my question please look at it. I found the main-wrap but not sure if it's right how i did it and in what html to add it to.

Comment: Okay. So I see the widget appearing on test.html and untitled.html.
You can put it in all of the main-wrap divs so it appears on every page.
Then it's a matter of positioning it to your liking. I simply created a div that floats all its content to the right side of the screen.

Comment: When you mean to copy the code into the new div you mean to put the widget code between ></div> ? between this two >< ?

Comment: Precisely. Like this `<div id="sidebar" style="float:right;">PUT DIV HERE</div>`
Replace "PUT DIV HERE" with the widget code.

Comment: Ok got it to work now last thing how do i change the widget width i mean to make it more thin ?

Comment: If you want a thinner widget than you should probably use the [current weather widget](http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets/current) Accuweather offers instead. Otherwise, you can try to modify the existing weather widget by setting the width of the div: `style="width:120px;"`. However, this will squish all of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Get the new updated code from accuweather.(You need to add this to your style.css)Where you place it is up to you (main menu).This will put it on the top right of the page.I was pulling my hair out for a day trying to get it to work.I know this is a two year old thread,but i thought id give back for all the help this site gave me.

```
.aw-widget-current .aw-widget-current-inner { /*+placement: 865px -334px;*/ position: relative; left: 865px; top: -334px; }
```